# Pusher with Laravel 5 Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, chat, pusher

I'm making an app with Live Chat in Laravel 5 and I'm following this tutorial, https://github.com/dazzz1er/confer/tree/master I already followed all of them but I'm having an error in my web console:

[image]

Seems like it's making an ajax call on my url http://localhost/joene_/public/index.php/auth and since I don't have a route to handle that request, it says 404. I don't know if should make a route for it but what will I code on there? I have no idea. The tutorial doesn't even mention it.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Whenever, you call `Auth::check()`, Laravel will verify if the user is authenticated by checking its session information.

What about **Pusher**? How will they know, which users are currently logged in on your laravel application?

The answer lies in the ajax call `http://localhost/joene_/public/index.php/auth`.

By calling the above URL, your laravel installation will let your Pusher application link with your users' laravel session.

**Let's dive into some code:**

*1) Pusher Auth Controller*

```
class PusherController extends Controller {

    //accessed through '/pusher/'
    //setup your routes.php accordingly

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        //Let's register our pusher application with the server.
        //I have used my own config files. The config keys are self-explanatory.
        //You have received these config values from pusher itself, when you signed up for their service.
        $this->pusher = new Pusher(\Config::get('pusher.app_key'), \Config::get('pusher.app_secret'), \Config::get('pusher.app_id'));
    }

    /**
     * Authenticates logged-in user in the Pusher JS app
     * For presence channels
     */
    public function postAuth()
    {
        //We see if the user is logged in our laravel application.
        if(\Auth::check())
        {
            //Fetch User Object
            $user =  \Auth::user();
            //Presence Channel information. Usually contains personal user information.
            //See: https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_presence_channels
            $presence_data = array('name' => $user->first_name." ".$user->last_name);
            //Registers users' presence channel.
            echo $this->pusher->presence_auth(Input::get('channel_name'), Input::get('socket_id'), $user->id, $presence_data);       
        }
        else
        {
            return Response::make('Forbidden',403);
        }
    }
}
```

*2) JS used with Pusher*

```
//replace 'xxx' below with your app key
var pusher = new Pusher('xxx',{authEndpoint : '/pusher/auth'});
var presenceChannelCurrent = pusher.subscribe('presence-myapp');
presenceChannelCurrent.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function() {
    alert(presenceChannelCurrent.members.me.info.name+' has successfully subscribed to the Pusher Presence Channel - My App');
});
```

Hope it helps you.