# what event-name should be used on broadcasting laravel notifications

Tags: javascript, php, pusher, laravel-5.3

I want to make real-time laravel notifications.

For that I done all [configurations described in docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#configuration).

My notification class is:

```
class NewChangeRegisterStatusNotif extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;


    public function __construct ($status_id, $course_id)
    {
        $this->status = CourseUserStatus::findOrFail($status_id);
        $this->course = Course::findOrFail($course_id)->first(['title']);
    }


    public function via ($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database', 'broadcast'];
    }


    public function toMail ($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
            ->action('Notification Action', 'https://laravel.com')
            ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }


    public function toArray ($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'message' =>
                'Some Messages'
            ,
            'action'  => '#'
        ];
    }
}
```

And Below codes, create a new Notification :

```
$user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
$user->notify(new NewChangeRegisterStatusNotif($value, $course_id));
```

and this is javascript client codes to bind and receive pusher events:

```
<script src="{{asset('link/to/pusher.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script>
            Pusher.log  = function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            };
            var pusher  = new Pusher("{{env("PUSHER_KEY")}}");
            var channel = pusher.subscribe('App.User.1');
                 channel.bind('Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        </script>
```

subscribing to `App.User.1` is succeeded in Debug Console Pusher.

Also in Laravel logs below message is shown :

```
[11:08:31] LOG.info: Broadcasting [Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated] on channels [private-App.User.1] with payload:
{
    "message": "Some Message",
    "action": "#",
    "id": "57d9e4dd-09cd-4cd2-ba3d-06f3fcf2af84",
    "type": "App\\Notifications\\NewChangeRegisterStatusNotif",
    "socket": null
}
```

But Problem is that `channel.bind()` does not fired.

As you Can see , I pass `Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated` to that and try escaped it `Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated` but None of them does not work.

What is Problem?

**Update:**

I found that Despite the Broadcasting event by laravel, but it does not sent to pusher or Pusher can not receive it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing below actions my problem is solved :

1- in the config/broadcasting.php file on line 18 , I change `'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'pusher'),` to `'default' => 'pusher',`.

2- changed `var channel = pusher.subscribe('App.User.1');` to `var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-App.User.{{$AuthUser->user_id}}');`

3- escaped `channel.bind('Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated'` to `channel.bind('Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated'`

Also I followed all instructions that described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30396900/498504

Answer (score 1):

Can you log into the Pusher dashboard, go to the debug console, and paste the JSON of the events that appear there when you trigger them from your Laravel code?

I suspect the reason you are not seeing them is because you need to bind to `private-App.User.1` and not just `App.User.1`.

Answer (score -1):

Simple add this method to you Event Class

```
public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'event-name';
}
```

You can read more in laravel documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#main-content
At section "Broadcast Name"

By default, Laravel will broadcast the event using the event's class name. However, you may customize the broadcast name by defining a broadcastAs method on the event:

```
/**
* The event's broadcast name.
*
* @return string
*/
public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'server.created';
}
```

If you customize the broadcast name using the broadcastAs method, you should make sure to register your listener with a leading . character. This will instruct Echo to not prepend the application's namespace to the event:

```
.listen('.server.created', function (e) {
    //....
});
```

Official Documentation:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223245/laravel-echo-not-listening-for-pusher-events