# Laravel Echo not listening for pusher events

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

Trying to create a kind of chat app with laravel and vuejs.
Once the message is sent, I fire the event from laravel which reflects on the pusher debug console with the right event class but the listen callback from vuejs is not called at all.

```
created () {
        window.Echo.channel('chat')
            .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
                console.log(e); //not getting this
                this.sentMessages.push({
                    message: e.message.message,
                    user: e.user
                });
            });

    },
```

Below is a screenshot of the debug console from pusher
[see the image here as am told I can't embed images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJFjV.png)

Comment: Any error on the console? Are you sure that the event is triggered from laravel? If so can you show the pusher debug console results for the event name?

Comment: @roliroli see the image link above

Comment: Have you tried setting `Window.Pusher.logToConsole = true` to make sure it's subscribing to the channel properly.

Comment: where do I set that and how will it help or what will I be expecting

Comment: Have you tried `.listen('App\\Events\\Chats\\MessageSent'`, console.log) ???

Comment: nope let me try it

Comment: Ok replace the whole .listen method with what I provided above and see the console

Comment: `App\\Events\\Chats\\MessageSent` this worked but, why is it?

Comment: because on the laravel you have setup as event the App\\Events\\Chats\\MessageSent

Comment: As you can clearly see on the screenshot you provided

Comment: Ok cool thanks, everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
created () {
        window.Echo.channel('chat')
            .listen('App\\Events\\Chats\\MessageSent', (e) => {
                console.log(e);
                this.sentMessages.push({
                    message: e.message.message,
                    user: e.user
                });
            });

    },
```

**By default, Laravel will broadcast the event using the event's class name. However, you may customize the broadcast name by defining a broadcastAs method on the event:**

```
public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'server.created';
}
```

> The above was copy pasted from [Laravel Broadcast Name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#broadcast-name)

My recommendation:

I have always used private channels for chat and you must too.
[Read here why](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_private_channels)

Comment: remember to add ' . ' before the full class name in the listen(). as seen from https://laravel.com/docs/master/broadcasting#namespaces

Comment: Hey, I have changed this for private channel and it is not working now?, what is it?

Comment: When you use private channels you have to authenticate users.

Comment: \\ double slash worked for me `.listen('\\Modules\\CitizenPortal\\Events\\Shootme', function (e) {` I am using Nwidart module package